# How can I merge 2 videos together in OpenCV? Similar to that of a SimulCam

Tags: c++, opencv, video, video-capture

I am looking for a way to combine/blend 2 videos irrespective of alignment in OpenCV.

I have 2 videos of the same scene, one is a ball rolling fast, the other slow from a standardised start point.

I have managed to work out how to use AddWeighted() previously to blend two images together, but have little knowledge of performing something similar for Videos.

I understand that it involves reading frames of the respective sources and processing them.. but that is all.

---

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Read some basic Opencv Tutorials on how to read a video file and fetch the frames from that file, Then simply apply your knowledge of `addWeighted` on the 2 frames fetched from respective videos

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks for the reply. I have investigated this and have used the image difference to output some results which are acceptable. I'll look into using addWeighted() on the individual frames soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

perform operation on every frame of video

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

video1 = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')
video2 = cv2.VideoCapture('output1.avi')

while True:

    ret1, frame1 = video1.read()
    ret2, frame2 = video2.read()
    if ret1==False or ret2==False:
        break

    frame1=cv2.resize(frame1, (240,320))
    frame2=cv2.resize(frame2, (240,320))

    dst = cv2.addWeighted(frame1,0.3,frame2,0.7,0)
    cv2.imshow('dst',dst)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```